# Spring Boot with Tomcat container security

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm trying to add Tomcat container security to a Spring Boot application (to take advantage of some legacy custom valves). With the snippet below (starting from the example at https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git) I expected basic authentication would kick in, but it doesn't. Tried with both Spring Boot 1.1.6 and 1.1.7.

The same configuration  when starting an embedded Tomcat "manually" (without involving Boot at all) works as expected.

```
 @Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(){
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {

            if(factory instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory){
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory;
                containerFactory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
                    @Override
                    public void customize(Context context) {

                        LoginConfig config = new LoginConfig();
                        config.setAuthMethod("BASIC");
                        context.setLoginConfig(config);
                        context.addSecurityRole("admin");

                        SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                        constraint.addAuthRole("admin");

                        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                        collection.addPattern("/*");
                        constraint.addCollection(collection);

                        context.addConstraint(constraint);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Does your project include spring-boot-starter-security?

Comment: The only dependency the spring guide example has is `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`, so no.

Comment: I'm not sure why your configuration above isn't working, but if you add spring-boot-starter-security, you shouldn't even need the configuration above; you'll get basic authentication for "free"